# Now() php insert date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im using now() to insert todays date in mysql table insert_date with date, it works fine, the problem comes to when i try to insert todays date +3 year from now now('+3 year') seems not to work.

php insert code

```
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO dokument (id, dok_typ, dok_num, namn, url,
insert_date,
update_date) VALUES('','".$dok_typ."',
'".$safe_dok_num."', '".$safe_namn."', '".$filename."', now(), 
 now()+ interval 3 year");
```

**EDIT**

Problem sloved with now() + interval 3 year

which will provide todays date 3 years in future.

Comment: Your code seems has error, the supplied value does not match with the table columns

Comment: simple `select NOW() + INTERVAL 3 YEAR from dual`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *the problem comes to when i try to insert todays date +3 year from now now('+3 year') seems not to work*

Use

```
now() + interval 3 year
```

as an expression in your query for the specific field.

BTW: I suggest you to use prepared statement to bind values with the query rather than directly placing the values between quotes and submit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `(curdate() + INTERVAL 3 YEAR)`.

Take a look at the relevant MySQL manual information http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html